# How to find out the amount of ppl simultaneously on a page/route in real-time in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

I don't know where to start.

I want to display the number of people watching a page/route simultaneously in real-time. Let me give you an example:

You are currently reading this question but you are not the only one, many other people have this page open in their browser right now as well. I want to find out that number and in realtime.

How can I do that? I imagine is a combination of both, front and back end. Just in case I'm using JS stack end to end.

I CAN'T USE WEBSOCKETS, only ajax request is available to me :(

Any clue?

Comment: Backend and frontend - web sockets is what you're looking for (socket.io for `node.js) - basically when someone loads the route, on the server they join a "room" - when people join this room / leave this room you send out an event to all users in the room the new room length - display that on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`angular-cookie`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) to simulate session.

keep a variable named `timeout` in cookies.